# Show that $f\equiv 0$ in $|z|<1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $f$ be analytic in $|z|<1$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)=\frac{1}{n}$ , for all $n>2$. Show that $f\equiv 0$ in $|z|<1$.

Since $f$ is analytic so Taylor's series expansion of $f$ is $$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k.$$

Letting $n\to \infty$ we get $f(0)=0$ and so $a_0=0$. Then,

$$f(z)=a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots$$

$$\implies f(1/n^2)=\frac{a_1}{n^2}+\frac{a_2}{n^4}+\cdots=\frac{1}{n}$$ Comparing the coefficients of $1/n^2$ , $1/n^4$ , ... we get $a_1=a_2=\cdots=0$.

Then $f\equiv 0$.

Is this proof correct ? If wrong how we can show it ?

Comment: When you compared coefficients on both sides, your conclusion that all of the $a_n$ terms must be zero would evidently imply that $1/n$ is zero.  But that cannot be true for all $n$.  In fact, the question is worded in a way that does not make sense to me.  How can a function $f(z)$ be $0$ for all $z$ and at that same time equal to $1/n$ when $z=1/n^2$?  Is this question from a book?  Perhaps $|f(1/n^2)|\le 1/n$.  Could that be correct?

Comment: @ Dr. MV) The question is from a exam. question paper...I have also doubt about the question...I am not sure whether the question is CORRECT or NOT..

Comment: The question is not correct. If you did not make a mistake writing it down, the poser of the exercise made a mistake. If a continuous function satisfies $f\bigl(\frac{1}{n^2}\bigr) = \frac{1}{n}$ for infinitely many $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then it cannot be differentiable at $0$. By continuity we have $f(0) = 0$, and then $$\frac{f\bigl(\frac{1}{n^2}\bigr) - f(0)}{\frac{1}{n^2}} = n^2\biggl(\frac{1}{n} - 0\biggr) = n.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no** function analytic in a neighborhood $U$ of $0$, and satisfying
$$f\left({1\over n^2}\right)={1\over n}\qquad(n\geq2)\ .$$
*Proof.* $\ $ Such a function would have to be $\not\equiv0$. Therefore there is an $r\geq0$ and another function $g$, analytic in $U$, with $g(0)=:c\ne0$, such that $f(z)=z^r g(z)$. We then would have
$${1\over n}=f\left({1\over n^2}\right)={1\over n^{2r}}\>g\left({1\over n^2}\right)\qquad(n\geq2)\ ,$$
or
$$g\left({1\over n^2}\right)=n^{2r-1}\qquad(n\geq2)\ .$$
But $n^{2r-1}$ does not converge to some $c\ne0$ when $n\to\infty$, whatever the value of $r\geq0$ might be.